# Arduino Project (TRAFFIC LIGHTS) *need ideas*

Tags: debugging, arduino

This is the code I have so far and I need help making the button which is on pin2 of the Arduino have an interrupt where if the lights can cycle on there own and if the button is pressed then it must kick on the yellow LED for 3sec and give the red LED for 10sec for the pedestrian to walk across. The cycle I have set but I need the pushbutton to work and im having difficulties making this work, any suggestions?

**CODE**

```
int red = 10;
int yellow = 9;
int green = 8;

int button = 2; // switch is on pin 2

void setup(){
pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
pinMode(button, INPUT);
digitalWrite(green, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH){
    delay(15); // software debounce
    if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) {
        // if the switch is LOW change the lights
        changeLights();
        delay(1000); // wait for 1 second
        }
    }  
}

void changeLights(){
// RED ON for 5 sec
digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
digitalWrite(green, LOW);
delay(5000);
// GREEN ON for 5 sec
digitalWrite(red, LOW);
digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
delay(5000);
// YELOOW ON for 3 sec
digitalWrite(red, LOW);
digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
digitalWrite(green, LOW);
delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: we usually expect people to try things themselves befor asking. your post suggests that you have not even searched the web for "arduino interrupt" as I don't find anything interrupt related in your code. so go out there, search the web find https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/ as the first hit, read it, try the example, modify the example, then you know how to use interrupts and can apply that knowledge to your project

Answer (score 0):

This is Arduinos example code for external interrupts:

```
const byte ledPin = 13;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
volatile byte state = LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), blink, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
}

void blink() {
  state = !state;
}
```

If the state of pinput pin `interruptPin` changes the microcontroller will service that interrupt calling `blink`. then it jumps back to into the application where it was interrupted.

So attach an interrupt service routine to your button pin and store in a variable the information that you should start the yellow red phase at the next chance.

as the yellow red phase usually cannot be interrupted you can use blocking code like delay to time it if your program is not controlling anything elss in the meantime.